# How Can I able acces Forms Pro Page html text in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, webclient, microsoft-forms

I am using Microsoft Forms for survey purposes and the URL for that form is

https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=BiopSuv_ckSNqp3fkzLnW_NGlVhpUkdKjXPYvQce5XRUQzgwTExXOU0wMlFIT0hFWUpIS04zTlhRVi4u

Now I when I open this form in a web browser it looks like below

[image]

When I read the same page with my below C# code then I am not able to find that HTML text which showing in Forms Pro Page in browser. instead, it showing me some javascript and other code.

```
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
           {
               string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=BiopSuv_ckSNqp3fkzLnW_NGlVhpUkdKjXPYvQce5XRUQzgwTExXOU0wMlFIT0hFWUpIS04zTlhRVi4u);
           }
```

So Is there any one way I can able to access that HTML text using my C# code which shows in the browser?

ex:- 1.Do you like this form.

Comment: That cant be done. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Umair  if someone filled up the form then it's shown Response Forms instead of the Survey Forms Pro pages. SO that things I need to check to remove that specific page.

Comment: You can not do like this. You will have to find another way.